# Maintaining Uniqueness of a column value even when historical data is archived from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

**Background Info:** I am working in a company where we have a table where the value of a particular column "Identifier" is supposed to be unique always. When we are inserting a new record in the table we always check that the value that we want to insert in "Identifier" column shouldn't match with any other record already present in the table and if it matches with any record then we try to generate another value for "Identifier" to maintain uniqueness.
There was no archival mechanism in place so far so this table has a huge amount of data resulting in latency issues because of which we want to archive the historical data which will go in a separate database.

**Onto the question:** If we archive the records from the table then there is a possibility when we can create an "Identifier" value which has been archived and our current logic for maintaining uniqueness will also fail so we will have duplicate values for "Identifier" (one in archived data and one in actual table).

I am looking for solutions where we can still maintain uniqueness of "Identifier" column values even when the old data is archived in another database.

Can someone please suggest any approach which can be used to resolve this issue?

Comment: how about a uuid?

Comment: Simplest solution - do not archive. More complex - create a table which contains identifiers only (including ones moved to the archive) and refer to it.

Comment: A filtered `UNIQUE INDEX`? This question, however, feels like it lacks focus or goes towards opinionated answers; as it's basically asking for people to "suggest ideas". [so] isn't a discussion website. There are many different solutions to such a problem, all with different pros and cons.

Comment: @Akina Archival is required because we are constantly seeing latency issues. 
If we create another table which only contains all the identifiers (Archived and Non Archived) and check for uniqueness on it, then also we will see the latency issues as the same amount of data would be there in the new table, Right?

Comment: @Larnu We have an UNIQUE_INDEX applied on the table but if the data is archived from that table then UNIQUE_INDEX would already be applicable for existing data in the table and not for Archived data.

Comment: Why I said a **filtered** `UNIQUE INDEX`, @sn54 .

Comment: A uniqueidentifier for sure. Or store your identifier values in a separate table which isn't part of the archive process.

Comment: No. The table must be indexed, so single value check must be fast.

Comment: @Akina I'm not sure which comment your comment was a reply to, but I think all the suggestions mentioned can be fast... potentially faster then the current solution.

Comment: @DaleK Of course, to the comment adressed to me. And, because of any nick absence, it was addressed to OP (primarily).

Comment: *"Of course, to the comment adressed to me"* all the comments, that aren't written by you, are addressed to you here (no one has pinged a different user in their comment); but there are multiple *other* users here so that doesn't tell us who you were addressing. As such we have no idea who you are replying to for [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66965067/maintaining-uniqueness-of-a-column-value-even-when-historical-data-is-archived-f#comment118371643_66965067), for example

Comment: If you posted your ID generation logic, somone might have a suggestion that appeals to you. Absent that, all anyone can do is guess and that makes the question off-topic.